# Laravel API call failed. PostMan overrides Authorization header with Basic Auth

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, postman

Hi am trying to call an API from Postman.
The framework used is : Laravel

The website has browser authentication (using .htacess)
And The API has user authentication (Laravel Passport) (user must be logged in)

Now,

I need to call an API and include both the headers, i.e.

- I added Basic Auth with username/pwd as browser credentials

  > > Basic Auth : username/pwd
- And in Headers I added

  > > Authorization : Bearer oauthtoken

(where oauthtoken is the key retreived from an API call https://servername/auth and Basic Auth : username/pwd)

Now when I send the API call,

The Authorization Header changes to :

> > Authorization : Basic some_key

And thus I get Unauthorized in response.
Is there some way I can send browser creds and user auth header together?

Answer (score 0):

Your OAuth token retrieved after authentication is not the same as the token attached by Postman for Basic Authentication.

If you wish to use your OAuth token in request I recommend looking at Postman variables and store that token in there.

[Here is an article that helped me build my Postman collection using JWT](https://medium.com/@codebyjeff/using-postman-environment-variables-auth-tokens-ea9c4fe9d3d7)

But some of the script in there is out of date.

I would start by creating an environment (local) in which you add a key to store the token (oauth_token) with value empty.

In the *auth* endpoint while in Postman you can check the *Tests* tab in which you can place a script to update the oauth token:

```
pm.test("Logged in successfully", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.environment.set('oauth_token', jsonData.token);
});
```

After this you can add Authorization Bearer with value *{{oauth_token}}* to an endpoint that is using OAuth token.

If you wish to learn more about Postman variables this is a great post [variables](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables)

To recap:

1. Send username and password to the auth endpoint
2. Store oauth token in Postman variable returned from step 1
3. Use your new token as Postman variable using {{*VARIABLE_NAME*}} notation

Answer (score -1):

I would advise to use [Guzzle Library](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/)

```
        $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
        $response = $http->request('POST', 'http://quotible.web3box.com/oauth/token', [
            'headers' => [
                //you headers here
            ],
            'form_params'=>[
                //your browser based parameters here
            ]
        ]);
```